# Split and group values in excel

Tags: excel, vba, split, group

Hi I have a column of values which has different suffix after a dot, i need it to group it based on the value after dot. Example i need to split all values that end with .pdf into one column, values with.xls as another column, etc,,,
[image]

how to do this is my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use nested dictionaries

```
Sub test()

    With New Scripting.Dictionary
        Dim cel As Range
            For Each cel In Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                If Not .Exists(Split(cel.Value, ".")(1)) Then .Add Split(cel.Value, ".")(1), New Scripting.Dictionary
                .Item(Split(cel.Value, ".")(1)).Add cel.Value, 1
            Next
        
            Dim iK As Long
                For iK = 0 To .Count - 1
                    Range("C1").Offset(, iK).Resize(.Items(iK).Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Items(iK).Keys)
                Next
    End With
    
End Sub
```

just add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

variant using `scripting.dictionary`:

```
Sub test()

    Dim dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim cl As Range
    
    For Each cl In [A1:A6]
        If Not dic.exists(Split(cl.Value, ".")(1)) Then
            dic.Add Split(cl.Value, ".")(1), cl.Value
        Else
            dic(Split(cl.Value, ".")(1)) = dic(Split(cl.Value, ".")(1)) & "|" & cl.Value
        End If
    Next cl
    
    Dim x%, i%, dKey, sVal
    
    x = 3
    For Each dKey In dic
        i = 1
        For Each sVal In Split(dic(dKey), "|")
            Cells(i, x).Value = sVal
            i = i + 1
        Next sVal
        x = x + 1
    Next dKey
        
End Sub
```

demo:

[image]