# Transpose in place in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a raw data which needs to be split into different columns, the raw data looks like
[image]

and i want the output to look like below.

[image]

I have a code which does the work when the Column A is not present, I need to modify it along with the column A

the code is

```
Sub transpose_in_place()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = .Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            For cl = .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 3 Step -1
                If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, cl)) Then
                    .rows(rw + 1).Insert
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 1) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 2) = .Cells(rw, cl).Value2
                    .Cells(rw, cl).clear
                End If
            Next cl
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Im not sure how to modify the code, can someone help me with it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub transpose_in_place()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            For cl = .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 4 Step -1
                If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, cl)) Then
                    .Rows(rw + 1).Insert
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 1) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 2) = .Cells(rw, 2).Value2
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 3) = .Cells(rw, cl).Value2
                    .Cells(rw, cl).Clear
                End If
            Next cl
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: BTW, did you have a chance to try my solutions in those other two post of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75195166/how-to-do-multiple-transpose-in-excel-vba  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75193871/split-and-group-values-in-excel?

Comment: Than you so much, It works exactly as needed.